# wp_enqueue script my_javascript_file in the footer

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, footer

I am trying to place `my_javascript_file` in the footer. According to the documentation `$in_footer` is the fifth value and it is a boolean so I have it set to `true`.
Currently it doesn't show up anywhere, as far as I can tell from inspecting the code.

Got it to work, it was hidden in a div I forgot to close (oops)

UPDATE *added fourth parameter as empty string `' '`*

FUNCTIONS.PHP FILE

```
<?php
function load_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script('my_javascript_file', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/app.js', array('jquery'),' ',true);
}    

add_action('init', 'load_scripts');
/*add_action('wp_footer', 'load_scripts');/*DELETED THIS PART
?>
```

FOOTER.PHP added wp_footer

```
</div>
    <!-- Main Row Ends -->
<?php wp_footer(); ?> /*added*/
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No need to enqueue jQuery, you're supplying it as a dependency already, it will be included. Doesn't make sense to add `load_scripts` on `wp_footer` action, it comes too late, when all scripts have been enqueued already.

Comment: You theme does not call `wp_footer()`, does it? The `$in_footer` parameter documentation goes on to state that ""This requires the theme to have the [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) hook in the appropriate place.""

Comment: @Soulseekah when you say supplying it as a dependancy already are you referring to the array(jquery) my theme does call wp_footer. I have added the footer.php file above now.

Comment: You are not calling wp_footer, right now you're adding a non-existing function to the wp_footer action. Replace that line with `wp_footer()` and that's it. `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` is not required, you are already including jquery as a dependency (`array('jquery')`), cleaner code.

Comment: @Soulseekah I added wp_footer to my footer.php file, but it still isn't working do I need the add_action in my functions.php file, I have tried with and without and it doesn't work still.

Comment: Does "the code" work if you set `$in_footer` to `false`, just to check?

Comment: @souldseekah, yes it works if I set $in_footer to false. I don't see why this isn't working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have `true` set in the 4th parameter (version), not the 5th.

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'my_javascript_file',                                 //slug
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/app.js', //path
    array('jquery'),                                      //dependencies
    false,                                                //version
    true                                                  //footer
);
```

Also, as someone else mentioned, drop jquery enqueue, you've got it as a dependency, you don't need to enqueue it as well.

One last thing, your function name has a good chance of breaking your site somewhere down the line. `load_scripts` has a pretty large chance of conflicting with something from the core or from the theme/plugin.

Comment: Ok I have dropped the query. Ill change the function name, thanks for the suggestion. But this still doesn't work. I copied and pasted your script even. I copied old code so my version did have the parameter as the 5th. Also do I need the add action for wp_footer

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference where it's enqueued. Does it enqueue properly if you set `$in_footer` to `true`.

Comment: Also //version is a string so should I not be placing empty quotes '' instead of false

Comment: I thought that $in_footer is set to true already.

Comment: My bad, I meant set `$in_footer` to `false`. `$version`'s default value is `false`, it sets the version to the current version of wordpress. If you want no version, pass in `NULL`. Have you read the [codex page about this function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)?

Comment: I keep rereading the codex over and over. It works if I set it to false.

Comment: Found it, jeez, it was hidden in a div I forgot to close. I should have searched for it in the first place. Thanks for your help.